# Can't get pagination to work for sticky posts only

Tags: query-posts, pagination, sticky-post

I don't get my pagination to work. I need to filter my posts on sticky posts and display only two per page. Tried almost everything but can't get it to work. It is totally ignoring my posts_per_page setting. Anyone got a suggestion?

```
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' =>2, 'paged' => get_query_var('page'), 'post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts'))); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php the_content(''); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>

    <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); ?></span>
    <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;'); ?></span>
```

Comment: Got it

    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=2' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged')); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer so this doesn't haunt site as unanswered.

Comment: fixed it, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

Got it

```
<?php 
    query_posts('posts_per_page=2' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged')); 
    if (have_posts()) : ?> <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

as simple as that.